# Mysql - associative table - Unknown column in on clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

The following query always returns #1054 - Unknown column 'T_RELATIF_SESS.REL_COM_ID' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT
`T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_ID`, 
`T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_TITRE`, 
`T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_NIVEAU`, 
`T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_MAX_PART`, 
`T_RELATIF_SESS`.`REL_COM_ID`, 
`T_RELATIF_SESS`.`REL_SES_ID`,
`T_SESSIONS`.`SES_ID`, 
`T_SESSIONS`.`SES_TITRE`, 
`T_SESSIONS`.`SES_TYPE`, 
`T_SESSIONS`.`SES_ADRESSE`, 
`T_SESSIONS`.`SES_NPA`, 
`T_SESSIONS`.`SES_LIEU`, 
`T_SESSIONS`.`SES_PRIX_SPECIAL`, 
`T_SESSIONS`.`SES_VAL_PRIX_SPECIAL`, 
`T_SESSIONS`.`SES_PRIX_SPEC_EXP`, 
`T_SESSIONS`.`SES_SUPP_COURS_INCL`, 
`T_SESSIONS`.`SES_SUPP_COURS_ADD`, 
`T_SESSIONS`.`SES_PRIX_SUPP_COURS_ADD`, 
`T_SESSIONS`.`SES_HORAIRE_SPECIAL`, 
`T_SESSIONS`.`SES_REMARQUES`, 
`T_SESSIONS`.`SES_REC_ID`, 
`T_COURS`.`COU_ID`, 
`T_COURS`.`COU_DATE`, 
    (SELECT `COU_DATE` FROM `T_COURS` WHERE `T_COURS`.`COU_SES_ID` = `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_ID` ORDER BY `COU_DATE` ASC LIMIT 1) AS `PREMIERCOURS`, 
    (SELECT `COU_DATE` FROM `T_COURS` WHERE `T_COURS`.`COU_SES_ID` = `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_ID` ORDER BY `COU_DATE` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `DERNIERCOURS` 
FROM `T_COURS` 
INNER JOIN `T_COMMANDES` ON `T_RELATIF_SESS`.`REL_COM_ID` = `T_COMMANDES`.`COM_ID` 
INNER JOIN `T_RELATIF_SESS` ON `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_ID` = `T_RELATIF_SESS`.`REL_SES_ID` 
INNER JOIN `T_SESSIONS` ON `T_COURS`.`COU_SES_ID` = `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_ID` 
INNER JOIN `T_FORMATIONS` ON `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_FOR_ID` = `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_ID` 
WHERE `T_COMMANDES`.`COM_ID`=19
```

This query worked fine before I add

```
INNER JOIN `T_COMMANDES` ON `T_RELATIF_SESS`.`REL_COM_ID` = `T_COMMANDES`.`COM_ID` 
INNER JOIN `T_RELATIF_SESS` ON `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_ID` = `T_RELATIF_SESS`.`REL_SES_ID`
```

And

```
WHERE `T_COMMANDES`.`COM_ID`=19
```

`T_RELATIF_SESS` is juste an associative table between the tables called "T_SESSIONS" and "T_COMMANDES".
I've tried to rewrite the query many times but I still get this error and I really don't understand why. Every field exists in my database.

I know it may be simple but it really gives me headache. Can someone can give me a hand or just explain to me what I do wrong? It would be much apprecietaded!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from your description you try to run the script without

```
INNER JOIN `T_COMMANDES` ON `T_RELATIF_SESS`.`REL_COM_ID` = `T_COMMANDES`.`COM_ID` 
INNER JOIN `T_RELATIF_SESS` ON `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_ID` = `T_RELATIF_SESS`.`REL_SES_ID`
```

and it is working, but not with that script? Try to make it in order, since on your first inner join, you are trying to join the table (T_COMMANDES) with the table that you will join next (T_RELATIF_SESS).

So try:

```
INNER JOIN `T_SESSIONS` ON `T_COURS`.`COU_SES_ID` = `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_ID` 
INNER JOIN `T_FORMATIONS` ON `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_FOR_ID` = `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_ID` 
INNER JOIN `T_RELATIF_SESS` ON `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_ID` = `T_RELATIF_SESS`.`REL_SES_ID` 
INNER JOIN `T_COMMANDES` ON `T_RELATIF_SESS`.`REL_COM_ID` = `T_COMMANDES`.`COM_ID`
```

Answer (score 1):

your order of table are messed up after you add your join, since you are using `INNER JOIN`, you can declare the table anywhere you like as long as the fields are visible on the joins. It will still yield the same result.

To solve the problem, put those new join on the lower part of your joins:

```
FROM    T_COURS 
        INNER JOIN T_SESSIONS 
            ON T_COURS.COU_SES_ID = T_SESSIONS.SES_ID 
        INNER JOIN T_FORMATIONS 
            ON T_SESSIONS.SES_FOR_ID = T_FORMATIONS.FOR_ID
        INNER JOIN T_RELATIF_SESS 
            ON T_SESSIONS.SES_ID = T_RELATIF_SESS.REL_SES_ID 
        INNER JOIN T_COMMANDES 
            ON T_RELATIF_SESS.REL_COM_ID = T_COMMANDES.COM_ID
```

The reason why an error message: `Unknown column 'T_RELATIF_SESS.REL_COM_ID' in 'on clause'` was thrown is because when joining `T_COURS` with `T_COMMANDES`, column `T_RELATIF_SESS`.`REL_COM_ID` isn't visible yet since you have declared table `T_RELATIF_SESS` on the lower part of the join.

Answer (score 0):

You try to access `T_RELATIF_SESS` before you have joined the table. You must join `T_COMMANDES` after `T_RELATIF_SESS` and `T_RELATIF_SESS` after `T_SESSIONS`

```
SELECT
`T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_ID`, 
...
FROM `T_COURS` 
INNER JOIN `T_SESSIONS` ON `T_COURS`.`COU_SES_ID` = `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_ID` 
INNER JOIN `T_FORMATIONS` ON `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_FOR_ID` = `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_ID` 
INNER JOIN `T_RELATIF_SESS` ON `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_ID` = `T_RELATIF_SESS`.`REL_SES_ID` 
INNER JOIN `T_COMMANDES` ON `T_RELATIF_SESS`.`REL_COM_ID` = `T_COMMANDES`.`COM_ID` 
WHERE `T_COMMANDES`.`COM_ID`=19
```